# Transform Entity-object into an Object with framework the MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have an entity that gets "userType" during a query to the database.

```java
public class OrderEntityXml {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "jpa.Sequence.t.order", sequenceName = "T_ORDER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "jpa.Sequence.t.order", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String customer;

    @Type(type = "Order")
    @Column(name = "order_xml")
    private Order order;

    public OrderEntityXml() {
    }
```

There is an container for getting from an entity.

This container is using by Jackson.

This container also is using marshaller and unmarshaller

```java
@XmlRootElement
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "order")
public class Order implements Serializable {


    private String customer;

    @XmlElement(name = "orderItem")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "orderItem")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public Order() {
    }
```

```java
public class OrderItem {

    private String sku;

    private Double price;

    public OrderItem() {
    }
```

I have set up a MapStruct.

- CycleAvoidingMappingContext - ( This is necessary to avoid Cycling (and the appearance of stack overflow))

```java
@Component
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {

    private Map<Object, Object> knownInstances = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>();

    @BeforeMapping
    public <T> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {

        T t = (T) knownInstances.get(source);
        return t;
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget Object target) {
        knownInstances.put( source, target );
    }
}
```

```java
public interface CommonMapper<D, E> {

    D toDto(E e, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    E toEntity(D d, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    Iterable<D> toListDto(Iterable<E> entityList);

    Iterable<E> toListEntity(Iterable<D> dtoList);

}
```

- MapperUtils - (This is utils for MapStruct)

```java
public static Order convertToDto(OrderEntityXml orderEntityXml){
        Order order = new Order();

        String customer = orderEntityXml.getCustomer();
        order.setCustomer(customer);

        Order xmlOrder = orderEntityXml.getOrder();
        List<OrderItem> orderItems = xmlOrder.getOrderItems();
        order.setOrderItems(orderItems);

        return order;
    }

    public static OrderEntityXml convertToEntity(Order order){

        OrderEntityXml orderEntityXml = new OrderEntityXml();
        String customer = order.getCustomer();
        orderEntityXml.setCustomer(customer);

        List<OrderItem> orderItems = order.getOrderItems();

        Order orderInEntity = new Order();

        orderInEntity.setOrderItems(orderItems);
        orderInEntity.setCustomer(customer);

        orderEntityXml.setOrder(orderInEntity);

        return orderEntityXml;
    }
```

- OrderDtoMapper - It is basic interface for me, for classes generation

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface OrderDtoMapper extends CommonMapper<Order, OrderEntityXml> {

    @Override
    default Order toDto(OrderEntityXml orderEntityXml, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {

        return convertToDto(orderEntityXml);
    }

    @Override
    default OrderEntityXml toEntity(Order order, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {

        return convertToEntity(order);
    }


    @Override
    default Iterable<Order> toListDto(Iterable<OrderEntityXml> entityList) {

        Iterable<Order> collect = StreamSupport.stream(entityList.spliterator(), false)
            .map(MapperUtils::convertToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return collect;
    }
}
```

For each data type, you will have to make your own utilities, and this is cumbersome.

Сan I remove extra code and configure it via MapStruct interfaces ? 
I suspect I've complicated the code.

Сan anyone tell you what needs to be tweaked or what technology can be applied to mapStruct to make the code unified

Comment: Is the `Order` in the `OrderEntityXml` the same class as the order being mapped into?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the posted entities I don't see why you need to use `CycleAvoidingMappingContext`. There is no cyclic dependency between your objects.

In order to avoid the manual code you've written you can use the MapStruct `@Mapping` annotation to customize how certain fields need to be mapped.

So in your case it would be something like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface OrderDtoMapper extends CommonMapper<Order, OrderEntityXml> {

    @Override
    @Mapping(target = "orderItems", source = "order.orderItems")
    Order toDto(OrderEntityXml orderEntityXml, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Override
    @Mapping(target = "order", source = "order")
    OrderEntityXml toEntity(Order order, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    Order cloneOrder(Order order);
}
```

The only customizations you need are the following:

- For `toDto` to tell MapStruct that when you are mapping from `OrderEntityXml` to `Order` you want to map the `order.orderItems` into the `orderItems`.
- For `toEntity` to tell MapStruct that you when you are mapping from `Order` to `OrderEntityXml` you want to map the method `order` parameters into the `order` of the `OrderEntityXml
- Additionally we add `Order cloneOrder(Order)` so that MapStruct creates a new object when mapping between `Order` otherwise the same object will be used.

The `customer` in both cases will be automatically mapped, since it matches on both sides.

There is no need to provide custom method for the `Iterable` mapping because MapStruct will do that automatically for you. It knows

Comment: Thank you.  Above the code is common example. Entities are more complex in my work project. Cyclic dependencies are there.

Comment: In that case you should add the `Context` to the Iterable methods as well. Otherwise you will have a problem for those entities.

Comment: This is not the case, I have not observed any problems. I just had to define the context in single methods, and MapStruct did everything by itself.